# Getting started with Boost Link errors

Tags: c++, boost

I am just getting started with Boost and trying the first example.  I says that it is header only.  I drop the code in and add the path for the additional include

> D:\boost_1_66_0\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
>   I also turned off precompiled headers.  I compiled the libraries and added the additional libraries path D:\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>



int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " ");
}
```

When I compile I get a link error

> cannot open file 'D\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib.obj

which seems very strange.

I am just trying to get started on this.  Thanks

Visual Studio 2015 Toolset v140

Comment: What command are you using to compile the code?

Comment: Maybe you added boost not as path but as lib.

Comment: Did you actually build boost before trying this? (The path you use makes me think you are not using the prebuilt package, which I would recommend using unless you reallly have a reason not to).

Comment: I am compiling within VS 2015.  My Additional include Directories is D:\boost_1_66_0;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories).  My Additional Dependencies is D:\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib\;%(AdditionalDependencies).  I added a trailing \ and now the error is "cannot opoen file 'D:\Boost_1_66_0\stage\lib\.obj'

Comment: Have you tried compiling it by hand? I feel like VS is doing something unseemly and that's causing your issue.

Comment: _My Additional Dependencies is D:\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib_ as I said...

Comment: I installed the prebuilt libraries and changed the Additional Dependencies path and get the error
cannot open file 'D:\boost_1_66_0\pre\lib64-msvc-14.0'

Comment: It looks like you've told VS to look for an IDE project file in the Boost directory, which it most certainly won't find. I'm really leaning toward this being an IDE issue.